# How can I embed extern JSP/HTML snippet of /ibm_security_logout into JSF?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, logout

I try to implement the `/ibm_security_logout` logic in a JSF project.
There are some requirements about the way which I should use for logging out.

It should conform this form:

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ibm_security_logout"
NAME="LogoutForm">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="logoutExitPage"
VALUE="/../weblogin/logout?dest=/myapp/goodbye.jsp">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="logout" VALUE="Logout">
</FORM>
```

Both cases must be there.

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ibm_security_logout"
VALUE="/../weblogin/logout?dest=/myapp/goodbye.jsp">
```

How can I realise it with commanlink?

```
<h:commandLink value="Log Out" action="#{sessionController.logout}" />
```

How should it look like in the bean method??

```
public void logout() throws IOException {

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession();
    ec.redirect("/../weblogin/logout?dest=/myapp/goodbye.jsp");

}
```

**EDIT**

`#{request.contextPath}`   =  localhost:9080/MyProject
Login Page = localhost:9080/weblogin/login?webapp=/MyProject  (Login Page is managed via) an extern Framework
Logout is also managed via an extern framework. Therefore the URL must conform this VALUE="/../weblogin/logout?dest=/weblogin/login?webapp=/MyProject.

I tried it with the code below. But it did not work.

```
<form id="logout" action="#{request.contextPath}/ibm_security_logout"
            method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="logoutExitPage"
            value="/../weblogin/logout?dest=/weblogin/login?webapp=/MyProject">
<a  href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout_NEU</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ExternalContext#invalidateSession()` alone is not sufficient. You absolutely need to POST to `/ibm_security_logout` directly if you have used IBM's login facilities. It will not only invalidate the session, but also clear out the SSO cookie and LPTA authentication. Otherwise the user would possibly still be auto-logged-in after invalidate.

You can just use plain HTML in JSF. I'd only neutralize those 90's style uppercased tags/attributes, because uppercased/camelcase HTML tags/attributes are invalid in XHTML (I assume that you're using Facelets; your question history at least confirms that you're using Facelets).

```html
<form action="#{request.contextPath}/ibm_security_logout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="logoutExitPage" value="#{request.contextPath}/home.xhtml">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

Or if you really need a link to submit the form,

```html
<form id="logout" action="#{request.contextPath}/ibm_security_logout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="logoutExitPage" value="#{request.contextPath}/home.xhtml">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout</a>
</form>
```

Note that the `logoutExitPage` must represent the URL of the landing page after logout. It doesn't necessarily need to represent exactly `/../weblogin/logout?dest=/myapp/goodbye.jsp`. That was just an example.

Comment: Does it also invalidate the jsf session?

Comment: The `/ibm_security_logout` already invalidates the session (among clearing the SSO cookie and LPTA authentication). So if you were using only `ExternalContext#invalidateSession()`, you'd still end up with a dangling SSO cookie in the client and LPTA authentication in the cache.

Comment: @DaDaDom: :) Even then, in JSF2 which uses the XML-based Facelets as default view technology, it would have thrown XML parsing errors/warnings because uppercased tags/attributes are invalid as per XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

Comment: The second link is also needed. See my Update please.

Comment: Please descibe "it did not work" in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. As first step, is the HTTP POST request fired with the desired parameters or not?